# Soundpool loop different for different devices android

Tags: android, media-player, soundpool

I have implemented **Soundpool** for playing a ring but unfortunately sound **loop** is **different** from *different devices*. 
My code is like this for sound pool

```
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = getActivity().getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.dummy);
    SoundPool soundPool  = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 100);
               int id  = soundPool.load(afd, 1);
               int loop = 3;
                soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool arg0, int arg1, int arg2)
                    {
                        soundPool.play(id, 1, 1, 1, loop, 1f);
                    }
                });
```

In Samsung deices loop execute properly 3 times but in Motorola device loop execute 4 times, I am not getting any proper solution. 
Any type of help ll be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if any help can be derived from http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-android-s-soundpool-class-a-tutorial.html  or not.. Just check the detailed implementation in the link'

Comment: Thanks for your comment but  i am integrated like this but cant find any solution